# Error: Model is large in H2o autoencoder training

Tags: h2o, dimension, reduction

I have a table of 5360*51200 size. Here, 5360 are the number of instances and 51200 are the number of features. I need to reduce the dimension of features. I was trying it by the help of stacked autoencoder in H2o, but it did not allow me to train to raise an error as:

```
Model is a large and large number of parameters
```

Here is the code:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

check.deeplearning_stacked_autoencoder <- function() {
  # this function builds a vector of autoencoder models, one per layer
  #library(h2o)
  #h2o.init()
  get_stacked_ae_array <- function(training_data, layers, args) {
    vector <- c()
    index = 0
    for (i in 1:length(layers)) {
      index = index + 1
      ae_model <- do.call(h2o.deeplearning,
                          modifyList(
                            list(
                              x = names(training_data),
                              training_frame = training_data,
                              autoencoder = T,

                              hidden = layers[i]
                            ),
                            args
                          ))
      training_data = h2o.deepfeatures(ae_model, training_data, layer =
                                         3)

      names(training_data) <-
        gsub("DF", paste0("L", index, sep = ""), names(training_data))
      vector <- c(vector, ae_model)
    }
    cat(
      length(vector))
  }

  # this function returns final encoded contents
  apply_stacked_ae_array <- function(data, ae) {
    index = 0
    for (i in 1:length(ae)) {
      index = index + 1
      data = h2o.deepfeatures(ae[[i]], data, layer = 3)
      names(data) <-
        gsub("DF", paste0("L", index, sep = ""), names(data))
    }
    data
  }

  TRAIN <-
    "E:/Chiranjibi file/Geometric features/Lu/Train/d_features.csv"
  TEST <-
    "E:/Chiranjibi file/Geometric features/Lu/Test/d_features.csv"
  response <- 51201

  # set to T for RUnit
  # set to F for stand-alone demo
  if (T) {
    train_hex <- h2o.importFile((TRAIN))
    test_hex  <- h2o.importFile((TEST))
  } else 
  {
    library(h2o)
    h2o.init()
    homedir <-
      paste0(path.expand("~"), "/h2o-dev/") #modify if needed
    train_hex <-
      h2o.importFile(path = paste0(homedir, TRAIN),
                     header = F,
                     sep = ',')
    test_hex  <-
      h2o.importFile(path = paste0(homedir, TEST),
                     header = F,
                     sep = ',')
  }
  train <- train_hex[, -response]
  test  <- test_hex [, -response]
  train_hex[, response] <- as.factor(train_hex[, response])
  test_hex [, response] <- as.factor(test_hex [, response])

  ## Build reference model on full dataset and evaluate it on the test set
  model_ref <-
    h2o.deeplearning(
      training_frame = train_hex,
      x = 1:(ncol(train_hex) - 1),
      y = response,
      hidden = c(67),
      epochs = 50
    )
  p_ref <- h2o.performance(model_ref, test_hex)
  h2o.logloss(p_ref)

  ## Now build a stacked autoencoder model with three stacked layer AE models
  ## First AE model will compress the 717 non-const predictors into 200
  ## Second AE model will compress 200 into 100
  ## Third AE model will compress 100 into 50
  layers <- c(50000,20000,10000,5000,2000, 1000, 500)
  args <- list(activation = "Tanh",
               epochs = 1,
               l1 = 1e-5)
  ae <- get_stacked_ae_array(train, layers, args)

  ## Now compress the training/testing data with this 3-stage set of AE models
  train_compressed <- apply_stacked_ae_array(train, ae)
  test_compressed <- apply_stacked_ae_array(test, ae)

  ## Build a simple model using these new features (compressed training data) and evaluate it on the compressed test set.
  train_w_resp <- h2o.cbind(train_compressed, train_hex[, response])
  test_w_resp <- h2o.cbind(test_compressed, test_hex[, response])
  model_on_compressed_data <-
    h2o.deeplearning(
      training_frame = train_w_resp,
      x = 1:(ncol(train_w_resp) - 1),
      y = ncol(train_w_resp),
      hidden = c(67),
      epochs = 1
    )
  p <- h2o.performance(model_on_compressed_data, test_w_resp)
  h2o.logloss(p)


}
#h2o.describe(train)

#doTest("Deep Learning Stacked Autoencoder", check.deeplearning_stacked_autoencoder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom says, your autoencoder first layer is too big.

51,200 is a lot of features. How much correlation is there between them? The more correlation you have, the smaller the first layer of your autoencoder can happily be.

Try `h2o.prcomp()` and seeing how many dimensions cover 99% of the variance, is often a good guide to how big your first layer can/should be.

Or, if you prefer a more experimental approach:

- Start with, e.g. 200 neurons in one layer.
- Look at the MSE it gets to, after enough epochs to stop improving.
- Double the number of neurons in that layer.
- See if the MSE gets any better. If not, stop there.
- If it did, double again, and repeat.

You could then try moving to multiple layers. But not much point using a bigger first layer than the best you can get from trying a single layer.

Comment: Thanks Darren! I am trying it now. Actually, the dataset was prepared by the extraction of features from pre-trained deep learning pooling layers. It is the features from indoor image. I am trying it and let you know what happens. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried to use h2o.prcomp(), but it gives an error: Gram matrices (one per thread) won't fit in the driver node's memory (4.060 TB > 18.85 GB) - try reducing the number of columns and/or the number of categorical factors.
 I am now trying with experimental way. Add some layers and experiment. Let you know what happens.

Comment: Re `h2o.prcomp` wanting 4TB for a matrix that should only need 2GB (at 8 bytes per value): are all the columns numeric, or are some factors?

Comment: Last column is factors which i remove for unsupervised training. The total size will be 5360*51200. All data are of float type. I also tried stacked autoencoder with fewer layers e.g 200 and trained with mse. It is giving less than 0.0108 loss for both validation and training set. I splited training set into train:val for 8:2 ratio. Is it a good direction?

Answer (score 1):

Since your dataset has 51,200 features, and your layers array has 50,000 as the first value, 51200 * 50000 == 2.56e9 weights in that first set of network connections.

It’s too many, try smaller numbers.